# Is it possible to backup and restore Thunar custom actions?

Tags: backup, file-manager, thunar

I think that  as far as file-manager context menu actions go, Thunar's are the most accessible and easy to manage, especially that the program is so light and easy to install.

I have always created a lot of such "customizations", but I never tried to back them up and restore them later.

Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Custom Thunar actions are stored in `~/.config/Thunar/uca.xml`; copying that file elsewhere will provide a backup that you can restore in future simply by copying it back.

When restoring a file, it’s worth checking to see whether the system you’re copying the file to has any interesting actions of its own (*e.g.* from new defaults in a newer version of Thunar). Each action in the file is stored as an `<action>` XML element; by copying these elements (`<action>`, the corresponding closing `</action>` and all the text in between), individual actions can be copied, or all the actions from the backup can be merged with the actions of the file in place.

Comment: Will the restoration work also in a different Linux installation?

Comment: Yes. You can even merge various actions from other systems (see the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ThunarCustomActions) for a number of examples).

Comment: So, when adding a backup to a new system that may have some new and good custom actions by default, the best solution is not to replace the default file with the backup, but to copy the backup text in the new file

Comment: Yes. I’ve added an explanation for how to merge two sets of actions.

Comment: And the keyboard shortcuts are defined in `~/.config/Thunar/accels.scm`

Comment: The outstanding question then is how best to generate unique numbers for any shortcuts you add to the file by hand/cmd line. Perhaps its good enough to just use any number not already taken.